# Simple ping script in kivy

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to make a simple a kivy script in python that ping http://google.com and if it successfully pings so it should show that the internet is on or off.I am making this script for android and I am little weak in kivy.Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried to fix it? Can you give some code you thought might work but doesn't?

Comment: I am trying to use kivy.request module to open a website....in python we have urllib to ping a website...so in kivy which library is insted of urllib and...how can i ping a website from kivy app ??

Comment: You can use other python modules as normal, kivy doesn't know or care about that, so use whatever you like. Requests and urllib are fine.

Comment: I already tried it...when i am importing urllib in kivy script and package that script and making apk by buildozer and deploying on android phone....it crash

Comment: Then let's debug the crash. You mean the apk building works but the apk crashes? If so, paste the full logcat output.

Comment: 'class TutorialApp(App):
 def build(self):
         do something

if urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com'):
 TutorialApp().run()

else:
 exit'

Comment: `class TutorialApp(App):`
 `def build(self):`
         `do something`

`if urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com'):`
 `TutorialApp().run()`

`else:`
` exit`

Comment: this is a basic coding i am making a script...if ping success so app will run...or it will exit......but in deployment is crashes...please help me

Comment: Explain clearly what goes wrong, and include the log output. Don't do this in comments, change the question or ask a new one.

Comment: Brother i dont have log....i just want to make an app that can run on phone only if internet is on....else it must be close...for that i used urllib and ping the website...if ping response app will run else it will exit...but here as above code app is crashing

Comment: There's always log output. On desktop it's output to stdout (in your terminal if you run that wa), on android it's accessible via the standard logcat tool.

Comment: I am using buildozer ...to make kivy or py to apk...and i can't find any log anywhere...